# php remove the carriage return on an assigned variable

Tags: php

If I assign a 2 lines value to a variable like this.

```
$tt = 'part 1
part 2 ';
```

and I echo it.

```
echo $tt;
```

My browser will display it on 2 lines and it's fine. But on the source page, the code will have it on 2 lines.

How can it get rid of this carriage return.
Since it',s not a chr(13) and a \r, these don't works.

```
echo str_replace(chr(13), '-', $tt);
echo str_replace('\r', '-', $tt);
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you don't want the line break, why include it in the first place?

Comment: \*cough\*cough\* **double quotes vs. single quotes** \*cough\*

Comment: Normally, a PHP file as you described will *not* show two lines in the browser (you would have to put in `<br />` or some other construct that forces a line break). So there is something you haven't told us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
str_replace(array(chr(13),chr(10)), "-", $tt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the environment you're in.  In Windows a line break is \r\n.  In *nix environments it's just \n.

```
echo str_replace("\r", "-", str_replace("\n", "-", $tt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way for Windows or Linux:

```
str_replace("\r\n", "-", $var);
```

On Linux, the \r\n still gets detected. Anything else suggested here is overkill (though not necessarily incorrect).

Keep in mind that you need to use double quotes when using special characters like \r or \n.

Edit:

If you want to be extra careful, you can use this instead:

```
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), "-", $var);
```

You shouldn't need any extra overhead of using the char() function, for something like \r or \n.